# Detect deletion of application users without User.Read.All permission

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to execute cleanup operations in an Azure AD application whenever a user is deleted. According to the Microsoft Graph docs, it seems like subscriptions and delta APIs are good options, but they require the `User.Read.All` permission. It‘s also possible to subscribe to individual user changes, but that‘s not an option since subscriptions are time-limited and limited to 100 per application.

Is there a way to detect disabled or deleted user without requiring permissions to real all users‘ data, like for example an „application users“ API that can be used to query data or subscribe to changes users who gave permission to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to achieve this today using Microsoft Graph.

A not-so-simple approach would be for your application to implement a [SCIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_for_Cross-domain_Identity_Management) service, and then [configure Azure AD to automatically sync changes to your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups). The advantage here is that only the user properties which are configured would get synced to your app, and only for those users/groups which have been assigned.

Note: Automatic provisioning with SCIM requires Azure AD Premium licenses.